# Gunicorn gets into error when start

Tags: python, django, nginx, virtualenv, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy my django project with gunicorn and nginx, i follow this guide: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/ . i created the bash script `gunicorn_start`: http://pastebin.com/J86MQZYa
but when i run this script, I get into error:

```bsh
alex@alex-VirtualBox:~/webapps/hello_ice1/bin$ sudo ./gunicorn_start
Starting icecream as root
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/alex/webapps/hello_ice1/icecream/../bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
File "/home/alex/webapps/hello_ice1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 71, in run
WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
File "/home/alex/webapps/hello_ice1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 28, in __init__
self.do_load_config()
File "/home/alex/webapps/hello_ice1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 32, in do_load_config
self.load_config()
File "/home/alex/webapps/hello_ice1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 99, in load_config
self.cfg.set(k.lower(), v)
File "/home/alex/webapps/hello_ice1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py", line 66, in set
self.settings[name].set(value)
File "/home/alex/webapps/hello_ice1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py", line 248, in set
self.value = self.validator(val)
File "/home/alex/webapps/hello_ice1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py", line 30, in _wrapped
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/alex/webapps/hello_ice1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py", line 374, in validate_group
raise ConfigError("No such group: '%s'" % val)
gunicorn.errors.ConfigError: No such group: ''
```

Hope that somebody can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You commented out the GROUP on line 7 while you are using it on line 29. As a result you are passing blank GROUP to the gunicorn, same goes for USER, if you do not want to change the default USER or GROUP, then do not pass it to the gunicorn.

From docs:

> A valid group id (as an integer) or the name of a user that can be retrieved with a call to pwd.getgrnam(value) or None to not change the worker processes group.

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html#group

Comment: thank you, i didn't see this line, when i execute again i have this error: http://pastebin.com/fLmuE3ki . Do I have to create the .wsgi module by myself?

Comment: Looking at the tutorial, yes you have to, check the directory structure at the end of the tutorial. I suppose you renamed the app name from "hello" to "icecream" so you need to rename these things accordingly.

Comment: yes, the name of the directories is correct. only difference is that the dir `run` is a root dir, and the settings are in subdirectories into the project (i have icecream.settings.base.py, ..local.py and production.py).

Comment: You will just have to adjust the paths according to your changes to the structure.

Comment: I know it's not a problem, i have changed the paths according to my structure. but the error remains.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41774/discussion-between-betelgeuse-and-jbub)